# Why doesn't document.body.style.backgroundImage work for the body element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say a HTML page that has the following CSS:

```
body { background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/200x200"); width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```

Why doesn't this:

```
console.log(document.body.style.backgroundImage);  // idem for .style.background
```

show the URL?

Instead, it shows a blank string.

Notes:

- it seems to works for a child `div`, but not for the body
- here a SO snippet wouldn't help (because this question is specifically for `body`)

Comment: "*it seems to works for a child div, but not for the body*" [no, it doesn't seem to](https://jsbin.com/nuxiyirula/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output). The `.style` only gives you inline styles. It's how it always worked. If you want the values from a stylesheet see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
var bodyStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
console.log(bodyStyle.backgroundImage);
```